# Order firestore docs by newest first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

So basically im adding docs like this:

```js
db.collection('posts').add({
                name: usernameFinal,
                photoUrl: photoFinal,
                text: caption,
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                isPost: true


      });
```

Then im mapping all the docs.

```
{posts.map(({id, post}) => {
            if(post.isPost == true){
              return <Post
              key={id}
              id={id}
              name={post.name}
              photoUrl={post.photoUrl}
              text={post.text}
              imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
      
              
      
              />
            }
    
  }
```

But when I map it, it's not in order. So how can I either add the docs in order or map them in order?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have any implicit data about the order/time of a document, so to allow the ordering you describe you will have to have a `Timestamp` field in each document.

Once you do have such a field (say `createdAt`), you can [order on it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) when
you [get the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) by calling:

```
db.collection('posts').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
```